# C++ and Enumerable

Tags: c++

I have a producer/consumers design in my application which implement Produce/Consume functions on user types. But it doesn't work very naturally with the standard library and especially with algorithms.

In C# there is the Enumerable and Observable concepts that can be used to easily implement stuff like this and get alot of nice free functionality.

In C++ there is the ios, istream, ostream, input_iterator, output_iterator concepts which I thought might be useful. But it seems to me that all of these are for primitive character types, e.g. char, int etc... and not for user types.

Sure I could use real functions such as Produce/Consumer and std::mem_fn for algorithms. But I was hoping there was a better way.

Im looking on some best-practice advice on how to go about designing i/o similar solutions on user types in C++.

E.g. from C#

```
class FrameProducer : IEnumerable<Frame> // pull frames
{...}

// Some engine between

class FrameConsumer : IObserver<Frame> // push frames
{...}
```

I was hoping for something similar in C++ e.g. which i dont believe is possible.

```
class FrameProducer : istream<Frame> // pull frames
{...}

// Some engine between

class FrameConsumer : ostream<Frame> // push frames
{...}
```

Maybe I'm thinking to hard about it and should just go by KISS.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why are you talking about C#? This is C++, forget you know C# and start programming in C++. Saying "I'd do it this way in language X, how can I translate it into language Y" will always fail, you must learn language Y from the ground up so you know how things are done in language Y. [A good book helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Oh, and I don't get the question. Whenever you bring language X into a problem about language Y, many people that know language Y need you to explain that X language feature.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean for "Produce/Consume functions on user types"?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language I'm talking about, it's not to the point. I just picked C# because it was convenient since it had the LINQ concept which is similar to C++ and its iterators and algorithms.

My question is why the C++ ios concept doesn't allow for user types and what alternatives there are.

Comment: I could for example implement a producer by having it provide an input_iterator instead of having a "Producer" function and in the same way a consumer by having it provide an output_iterator. Im just looking for a best practice.

Comment: produce/consume on user types.

struct MyProducer
{
     MyNiceClass Produce();
};

struct MyConsumer
{
     void Consume(const MyNiceClass& item);
};

Comment: How then would i implement iostream::getline on a user type?

My goal is to use the infrastructure provide by stl if possible instead of making up my own.

Comment: @Dacav I guess OP meant that Producer produces class instances rather then primitive types (such as `int`, `char`, etc).

Comment: C++ *does* allow user types to be streamed, by overloading insertion and extraction operators. (I think the problem is your question asks about a step, rather than a problem. Your comment above actually describes a problem, which can be answered.)

Comment: I am simply astonished people are not familiar with and therefore reject the ENTIRE body of work called COMPARATIVE ANALYSIS and the entire body of LOGIC in relation to Comparative Analysis. It’s a great way to force yourself into a barren intellectual ghetto. Enjoy the soulless rap.

Comment: Are you familiar with duck typing? That's generally how C++ deals with IEnumerable and the like.  If you want to write to streams, then overload <<. If you want to iterate over a collection, make something that looks like an iterator. Your FrameProducer would likely provide a `begin()` and `end()` method that produces those iterators, which would allow it to be used places that expect traditional containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th terms are "insertion operator" and "extraction operator", which insert and extract data from a stream.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct foo
{
    int x;
};

// insertion operator
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const foo& f)
{
    s << f.x; // insert a foo by inserting x
    return s;
}

// extraction operator
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, foo& f)
{
    s >> f.x; // extract a foo by extracting x
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    foo f1 = {5};
    ss << f1;

    foo f2;
    ss >> f2;
}
```

---

Based on your desire to do:

```
MyFrameProducer producer;
MyFrameConsumer consumer;
Frame frame; // frame should probably be in the while loop, since its 
while(!producer.eof()) // lifetime doesn't need to exist outside the loop
{
    producer >> frame;
    consumer << frame;
}
```

You might make:

```
struct MyFrameProducer {}; // add an eof function
struct MyFrameConsumer {};
struct Frame {};

// producer produces a frame
MyFrameProducer& operator>>(MyFrameProducer& p, Frame& f)
{
    /* whatever it takes to make a frame */

    return p;
}

// consumer consumes a frame
MyFrameConsumer& operator<<(MyFrameConsumer& c, const Frame& f)
{
    /* whatever it takes to use a frame */

    return c;
}
```

Or something akin to it. (Sorry my understanding of the problem is small.) It *is* a bit weird to desire this interface, since it has nothing to do with streams, and you might be better off with a different interface (explicit methods).

Comment: Not quite, what you show is how to convert a user type to a string.

I was looking for something like this (which doesn't work since the stl istream/ostream seems to be character based)

class MyFrameProducer : istream
{
}

class MyFrameConsumer : ostream<Frame>
{
}

int main()
{
     MyFrameProducer producer;
     MyFrameConsumer consumer;

     Frame frame;
     while(!producer.eof())
     {
          producer >> frame;
          consumer << frame;
     }
}

Comment: @ronag: I did *not* show how to convert a user type into a string, I showed how to insert it into a stream. (Only coincidentally does `stringstream` provide a way of producing a string.) Let me edit the answer to your comment snippet.

Comment: @Philipp: No, don't worry. I made it CW because I'm basically guessing, it wasn't your edit. And thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) producer/consumer solution. Although it is in pure C it is so elegant so I just can't resist from posting it.

Comment: Interesting, this seems also interesting: http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/